# Maven assembly jar: JCE cannot authenticate the provider BC

Tags: java, maven, jar, bouncycastle, maven-assembly-plugin

I'm developing an app that takes a XML file, sends it to a server, and receives some data in response. I need to package it into an .exe(legacy reasons), and for that I need a jar. I intend to use assembly plugin to package the app into a jar with all the dependencies. The app works fine when run from the IDE with

```
mvn clean package exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="cz.tomasdvorak.eetdemo.Main" -Dexec.args="C:\\eetTesting\\testtrzba.xml"
```

but as soon as I build the standalone .jar with `mvn clean compile assembly:single` and try to run it through

```
java -jar eet-demo-maven-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar "C:\\eetTesting\\testtrzba.xml"
```

it throws the exception described above. How is that possible? Bouncycastle is a dependency of one of *my* dependencies, I didn't do anything to it, I didn't even know it exists until now. Also, other parts of the app seem to work fine, for example a check that ensures that it is not ran with a wrong number of arguments. Maybe it's Maven configuration somehow? Including pom for reference:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>cz.tomasdvorak.eetdemo.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <artifactSet>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>org.bouncycastle:*:*:*</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </artifactSet>
                <transformers>
                    <transformer
                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Main-Class>cz.tomasdvorak.eetdemo.Main</Main-Class>
                            <Class-Path>. ./lib/bcprov-jdk16-1.46.jar</Class-Path>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </transformer>
                </transformers>
                <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                <shadedClassifierName>fat</shadedClassifierName>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

    <groupId>cz.tomasdvorak</groupId>
    <artifactId>eet-demo-maven</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jitpack.io</id>
            <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.todvora</groupId>
            <artifactId>eet-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

How do I fix this?

EDIT; full stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" cz.tomasdvorak.eet.client.exceptions.InvalidKeystoreException: java.io.IOException: error constructing MAC: java.lang.SecurityException: JCE cannot authenticate the provider BC
        at cz.tomasdvorak.eet.client.security.ClientKey.getKeyStore(ClientKey.java:84)
        at cz.tomasdvorak.eet.client.security.ClientKey.<init>(ClientKey.java:38)
        at cz.tomasdvorak.eet.client.EETServiceFactory.getInstance(EETServiceFactory.java:20)
        at cz.tomasdvorak.eetdemo.Main.main(Main.java:71)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error constructing MAC: java.lang.SecurityException: JCE cannot authenticate the provider BC
        at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.keystore.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStoreSpi.engineLoad(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.KeyStore.load(Unknown Source)
        at cz.tomasdvorak.eet.client.security.ClientKey.getKeyStore(ClientKey.java:75)
        ... 3 more
```

Comment: Can you show full stacktrace?

Comment: Added, is it of any help?

Comment: Bouncy Castle is signed library in order to work as JCE provider. You can not ship it inside Fat jar (jar with all deps). Exclude it from inclusion in jar and ship it with your app separately.

Comment: How would I do that, exactly? I have meanwhile found some answers for similar questions, but I still can't extrapolate the exact solution from them. I must be missing a version number or some other whatnot in there and it still gives the error. The most promising solution branch currently is the one using the maven-shader plugin. I'm adding the new part to the pom now. Could you please have a look at it and try to figure out what's missing or wrong in there?

Comment: How are you creating your exe. If you are using IzPack or Launch4j then it is easier than maven shade plugin

Comment: I plan on using Launch4j arbitrarily. How would I fix the problem using that solution instead?

Comment: In that case do not use maven shade plugin, but use [this](https://github.com/lukaszlenart/launch4j-maven-plugin/blob/master/src/main/resources/README.adoc)

Comment: Thanks, I'll read through it and give it a shot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125501/discussion-between-sargon1-and-sangram-jadhav).