# Maven Launch4j Plugin - how to configure to exclude jars used by the .exe?

Tags: java, maven, jar, pom.xml, launch4j

I'm developing an app that takes some arguments, sends some data to a server, and receives a response. It will only be called by another app and only uses CLI interface. Its dependencies are resolved by Maven. I need to package it into an .exe(legacy reasons). Also, one of the dependencies of my app uses some Bouncy Castle jars, which cannot be packaged normally with Maven assembly plugin because they lose their signatures.

As a solution, it has been [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39993855/maven-assembly-jar-jce-cannot-authenticate-the-provider-bc?noredirect=1#comment67268324_39993855) to me in another question that I use Maven's Launch4j plugin to both exclude the BC jars and build the exe. However, I can't for the life of me figure out how to configure it correctly. I don't even know where to begin to look for the way to exclude the BC jars and I have no idea how to cope with the classpath-related quirks of the plugin. The plugin's [readme](https://github.com/lukaszlenart/launch4j-maven-plugin/blob/master/src/main/resources/README.adoc) is too sparse a documentation for my limited grasp on Maven.

The POM as it currently is neither builds an .exe, nor gives any error message, making pinpointing the error that much harder. The size of the .jar in /target is the same as it was before, hinting that the build process does not seem to be any different from what it was before the plugin was added.

Could someone please have a look at the POM and suggest some improvement to make the app build as intended? Any help, especially an explanation of why the incorrect parts were changed the way they were, would be greatly appreciated.

Current POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                            <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                            <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.akathist.maven.plugins.launch4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>launch4j-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>l4j-clui</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>launch4j</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <dontWrapJar>true</dontWrapJar>
                            <headerType>console</headerType>
                            <jar>eet-demo-maven-1.0-SNAPSHOT-eet-sender.jar</jar>
                            <outfile>target\EETSender.exe</outfile>
                            <errTitle></errTitle>
                            <cmdLine></cmdLine>
                            <chdir>.</chdir>
                            <priority>normal</priority>
                            <downloadUrl>http://java.com/download</downloadUrl>
                            <supportUrl></supportUrl>
                            <stayAlive>true</stayAlive>
                            <restartOnCrash>true</restartOnCrash>
                            <manifest></manifest>
                            <icon></icon>
                            <singleInstance>
                                <mutexName>EETMutex</mutexName>
                                <windowTitle></windowTitle>
                            </singleInstance>
                            <classpath>
                                <mainClass>cz.tomasdvorak.eetdemo.Main</mainClass>
                                <postCp>\lib\bcprov-jdk15on-1.55.jar;\eet-demo-maven-1.0-SNAPSHOT-eet-sender.jar;\eet-demo-maven-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar</postCp>
                            </classpath>
                            <jre>
                                <path></path>
                                <bundledJre64Bit>false</bundledJre64Bit>
                                <bundledJreAsFallback>false</bundledJreAsFallback>
                                <minVersion>1.6.0_1</minVersion>
                                <maxVersion></maxVersion>
                                <jdkPreference>preferJre</jdkPreference>
                                <runtimeBits>64/32</runtimeBits>
                            </jre>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <mainClass>cz.tomasdvorak.eetdemo.Main</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
        <descriptors>
            <descriptor>assembly.xml</descriptor>
         </descriptors>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

    <groupId>cz.tomasdvorak</groupId>
    <artifactId>eet-demo-maven</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jitpack.io</id>
            <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.todvora</groupId>
            <artifactId>eet-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

assembly.xml:

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
    <id>eet-sender</id>
    <formats>
        <format>.jar</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.build.directory}/package</directory>
            <outputDirectory>/target</outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>*.exe</include>
            </includes>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>org/bouncycastle/*.*</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

Now then, what would be the proper configuration to ensure that at the end, there is an .exe which when ran with the correct arguments will execute its intended functionality?

Comment: Why are you using a fat jar at all? You can simply put all of your libs to `lib` and it will work.

Comment: How would I exactly do that, step by step? There is no library folder anywhere in the project. And would I download all the libs and their dependencies, anyway? Never did that before, Maven just got them for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some experimenting to try out Michael-O's suggestion, I have arrived to a pom that performs as required. Build with "mvn package". The result is the desired .exe along with all the dependency jars in the target folder. Having them separated by in a `lib` folder would be a more standard and elegant solution, but this is a really simple app and I'm on a tight schedule, so I'm just going to leave it as it is. The winner is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                            <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                            <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.akathist.maven.plugins.launch4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>launch4j-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>l4j-clui</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>launch4j</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <dontWrapJar>true</dontWrapJar>
                            <headerType>console</headerType>
                            <jar>eet-demo-maven-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar</jar>
                            <outfile>target\EETSender.exe</outfile>
                            <errTitle></errTitle>
                            <cmdLine></cmdLine>
                            <chdir>.</chdir>
                            <priority>normal</priority>
                            <downloadUrl>http://java.com/download</downloadUrl>
                            <supportUrl></supportUrl>
                            <stayAlive>true</stayAlive>
                            <restartOnCrash>true</restartOnCrash>
                            <manifest></manifest>
                            <icon></icon>
                            <singleInstance>
                                <mutexName>EETMutex</mutexName>
                                <windowTitle></windowTitle>
                            </singleInstance>
                            <classpath>
                                <mainClass>cz.tomasdvorak.eetdemo.Main</mainClass>
                            </classpath>
                            <jre>
                                <path></path>
                                <bundledJre64Bit>false</bundledJre64Bit>
                                <bundledJreAsFallback>false</bundledJreAsFallback>
                                <minVersion>1.6.0_1</minVersion>
                                <maxVersion></maxVersion>
                                <jdkPreference>preferJre</jdkPreference>
                                <runtimeBits>64/32</runtimeBits>
                            </jre>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <mainClass>cz.tomasdvorak.eetdemo.Main</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
        <descriptors>
            <descriptor>assembly.xml</descriptor>
         </descriptors>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

</plugins>
    </build>

     <groupId>cz.tomasdvorak</groupId>
    <artifactId>eet-demo-maven</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jitpack.io</id>
            <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.todvora</groupId>
            <artifactId>eet-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: right, definitively an easy approach is to the problem.

Answer (score 2):

As you told the problem with *BouncyCastle* is that is signed with a oracle issued certificate in order that it can work as a *JCE* provider.

Then you've to avoid to warp the `bcprov.jar` jar (this is the jar which include the JCE provided and its mandatory to be signed) inside a fat jar with all dependencies, because this way it breaks the *BouncyCastle JCE* jar signature.

So the thing is probably to avoid to warp the `bc-prov.jar` into `jar-with-dependencies` and and told install4j to load the jars from a folder as a classpath resource of your java execution.

To do so do the follow:

Add `<dontWrapJar>true</dontWrap>` and also use:

```
<classpath>
    <mainClass>cz.tomasdvorak.eetdemo.Main</mainClass>
    <postCp>\lib\to\yourBc\bc-prov.jar;lib\to\yourJar\eet-demo-maven-1.0-SNAPSHOT-eet-sender.jar</postCp>
</classpath>
```

To make sure that your `eet-demo-maven-1.0-SNAPSHOT-eet-sender.jar` not include the *BouncyCastle JCE* jar; you must change your *pom.xml* to make `maven-assembly-plugin` to point to your `assembly.xml`:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <mainClass>cz.tomasdvorak.eetdemo.Main</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
        <descriptors>
            <descriptor>/path/to/assembly.xml</descriptor>
         </descriptors>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

And then in your `assembly.xml` try to exclude *BouncyCastle* provider classes:

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
    <id>eet-sender</id>
    <formats>
        <format>jar</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
     <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
            <unpack>true</unpack>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.build.directory}/package</directory>
            <outputDirectory>/target</outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>*.exe</include>
            </includes>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

Note that this `assembly.xml` works basically as `<descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>` but excluding `org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on` artifact which comes as a dependency for your `com.github.todvora:eet-client`. This way you will have a fat jar with all dependencies excluding the *BouncyCastle* provider, which must be loaded separately then in the classpath execution for launch4j.

I hope that this way it works.

Comment: I'm figuring out the correct places to put all those things in, hang on. Also, about the last point, how would I write that into Maven?

Comment: One more thing, the documentation for the plugin says that it does not take <cp>, havin some different tags instead. How would I write that using those? https://github.com/lukaszlenart/launch4j-maven-plugin/blob/master/src/main/resources/README.adoc

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Adapting and testing, hang on.

Comment: Ok, there's still two issues: 1. It throws a "no main manifest attribute". I solved this one before, and I could just copy over the solution and hope it will work, but I thought that the `<mainClass>` tag takes care of that. How comes that it doesn't? What exactly that tag does? 2. How would I best obtain `jar-with-dep.jar` within Maven? Any way of telling it to take all the jars from /lib except BC ones and package them into one?

Comment: @Sargon1 finally, I try directly your *pom.xml* to avoid make you try/error... with the configuration I show in last edit it works for me generating a fat jar with all dependencies excluding the bc-prov ones.

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but I'm still getting the "no main manifest attribute" error when I run the resulting exe. I have updated the pom in the question to its current state. I suspect the fault is somewhere in the <classpath> or <manifest> tag. Furthermore, the .jar I'm getting doesn't seem that "fat". The `lib` folder has 33MB, while the generated jar only takes up 9KB, and the exe 30KB. Is "mvn clean package" even the right command to do the build?

Comment: @Sargon1 to generate the "fat" jar I do `mvn assembly:assembly`.

Comment: Now it gives "Error: Could not find or load main class cz.tomasdvorak.eetdemo.Main" I updated the pom again. Maybe it has to do with that "-eet-sender" appendix in the name on the fat jar? Could you please post your complete pom, to clarify things more? If it works for you we must be getting close.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125925/discussion-between-albciff-and-sargon1).